# Not enough space for 105M archives when 869M is left

Tags: apt, filesystem

The command `sudo apt-get upgrade` says

> [...]
>
> Need to download 105 MB in archives.
>
> After this operation, 2.108 kB disk space will be used
>
> E: Not enough space in /var/cache/apt/archives

(This is translated from a German system. Don't expect it to be 100% correct).

I'm using an 8 GB Micro SD Card and there should be plenty of space left. I checked with `df -h`.

```
[...]
/dev/root     7.2G     6.0G    869M     88%    /
```

I understand that 7.2G - 6.0G can be less than 1.2G, because of file system overhead.

However, I don't see why downloading 105M should be a problem.

I was able to solve the problem by freeing additional 540M from the recycle bin, but I'd still like to understand why apt-get complains about disk space when there's enough disk space left (IMHO).

Additional information that was requested:

Yes, all `/var` and its subdirectories are on `/dev/root`. It's a default Raspbian installation. I checked all of them with `df -P <dir>`:

```
$ df -P /var
[...]
/dev/root    7527272   5999148    1158916   84%    /
```

Comment: is /var actually mounted under / ? It is possible that it is a separate partition. a full df -h would be helpful to determine that. Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, /var is on /. I added that information (output of `df -P /var`)

Comment: How about `/var/cache`? Could that be a temporary filesystem? Output from `mount` or `cat /proc/mounts` will tell you. Also, it'd be nice if could maybe try `sudo apt-get -d upgrade` if it happens again to see if the new archives can at least be downloaded.

Comment: The `Why apt-get complains about disk space when there's enough disk space left?` is a unix.stackexchange.com question... isn't it?

Comment: @GramThanos: yes, maybe. However, the context may help, e.g. it may happen more often due to limited SD card sizes. Also, we can assume the default partition layout. It may especially help people finding a solution when they google for Raspberry + this error message. I feel quite ok leaving the question here, but that's for the community to decide.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Ext filesystems reserve 5% of space when partitioned.

(*Expanding on my earlier answer per @ThomasWeller request:*)

Let's take a look at my 32GB MicroSD card I ***dd***'ed Raspbian on to.

***fdisk -l*** (output truncated) shows of my 32GB card, the root filesystem ***/dev/mmcblk0p2*** occupies 29.7GB:

[image: Output of fdisk -l]

***df -h*** thus shows "30G" as total size. However, if we add "***Used***" + "***Avail***" this totals only ***28.2G***:

[image: Output of df on a 32GB MicroSD Card]

***Are 1.8GB missing?***

1.8G/30G total = 6%  With rounding, that approximates the size of the 5% reserved space. So "30G" is the ***absolute*** TOTAL space and "28.2G" is the ***effective*** USABLE space as I can't use that 5% for general purposes.

Also, you can have files that were deleted, but the space they consumed is not thrown back into the storage pot for re-use until the process has been killed (or you reboot which will clear the process). You can analyze situations like this using ***sudo lsof +L1***.  Specimen output follows:

[image: Output of sudo lsof +L1]

So output of ***df*** can be a bit confusing and when trying to free space, files you deleted might not be reflected in the "Avail" total in ***df*** results making them even more confusing ;-)

Comment: 5% of 8G is 400M. 869M free - 400M reserved = 469M. Still enough to download 105M, isn't it? Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: The 5% isn’t against the 8GB, it’s against that 7.2 GB. That’s the starting point for your calculations of the 5% reserved space

Comment: regarding 7.2G: In that case it becomes even less understandable: 5% of 7.2G is only 360M. 869M - 360M = 509M.

Comment: Have you tried hunting for files which are deleted, but the system doesn't yet recognize that free space with **sudo lsof +L1** as suggested in the second part of my answer?  That can throw-off the figures **df** displays.

Comment: No, I haven't. However, since I'm doing hardware development as well (using GPIO), I shutdown the machine often when I make changes.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `apt` but it has the same functionality than `apt-get`. Here is a typical **upgrade**:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-six
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 73.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/ui armhf python3-six all 1.12.0 [13.3 kB]
Fetched 13.3 kB in 6s (2,159 B/s)
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 34672 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-six_1.12.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-six (1.12.0) over (1.10.0-3) ...
Setting up python3-six (1.12.0) ...
2019-01-31 17:18:04 py2deb.hooks[2622] INFO Generated 1 Python bytecode files(s) for python3-six package.
```

As you can see it is announced
`Need to get 13.3 kB of archives.`
and exactly this is done with
`Fetched 13.3 kB in 6s (2,159 B/s)`.

Afterwards `apt` is doing

```
Preparing to unpack .../python3-six_1.12.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-six (1.12.0) over (1.10.0-3) ...
Setting up python3-six (1.12.0) ...
```

Unpacking the downloaded package and setup it up needs additional storage space that does not get into count of `Need to get 13.3 kB of archives.` This is what you give the error message if there is not enough space left.

Btw. doing `apt clean` before upgrading and using `apt full-upgrade` will clean up some storage.